# How to trigger an action after an update in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically I have something like:

```
TABLE PARENTS
...
name VARCHAR(45)
lastModified DATETIME
idModified INT
...

TABLE CHILDRENS
...
name VARCHAR(45)
parentName VARCHAR(45)
lastModified DATETIME
idModified INT
...
```

So what I want is when I perform:

```
UPDATE CHILDRENS SET lastModified=NOW(), idModified=123 WHERE NAME='someName';
```

The parent specified in parentName must also get updated with that same data.

I could do it manually, via the programming language I use, but that's not the point, I don't want to send another request to the database.

---

EDIT: I'm new to mysql, I don't know how to use triggers, oh I wrote childrens; bad grammar, sorry.

Comment: Well, you answered it yourself really. You create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger :)

Comment: How about using a trigger? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER triggers_name
AFTER UPDATE 
ON
CHILDRENS
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE PARENTS,NEW
        SET PARENT.lastModified=NEW.lastModified,
            PARENT.idModified=NEW.idModified
        WHERE PARENT.name=NEW.parentName
```

hope it works now becouse i cant test it right now :/

Comment: but the trigger must specify the values inside the childen instead NOW() and 123, will that trigger work for any values?

Comment: it says that I have an error in my MySQL syntax near ON CHILDRENS

Comment: my bad that was a trigger for SQL i will create one for MYSQL wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58006/discussion-between-youness-and-felishia).